# System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<String, bool> does not contain a definition for 'Where'

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to filter a dictionary here in a .NET 3.5 class library project, using linq expressions. Problem I am having is I don't seem to have the right dlls referenced to carry this out, it seems.

When I try to put the following code in

```
foreach (var item in TempFilesdictionary.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == false).ToList())
{
    dic.Remove(item.Key);
}
```

I get the error message . . .

`System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<String, bool>` does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<String, Bool>`  could be found

What libraries do I need to reference in my .NET 3.5 library to access the linq extension methods, apart from System.Core.dll, System.dll, System.Xml.Linq?

Comment: Are you declaring a using for Linq? `using System.Linq;`

Comment: BTW, `== false` is equivalent to `!`, except for `bool?`.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add a `using` directive for `System.Linq`.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was missing a lib using but since I already had System.Core, and System.Xml.Linq referenced, I figured that would auto suggest the next lib to add. But that did not happen.

Comment: that is a `using` *directive*, not a `using` *statement* (sorry if that is pendatic)

Comment: @MarcGravell: True; fixed.